# Gutenberg Block checkbox check-unckeck does not work

Tags: block-editor

I have added the custom Gutenberg block for my shortcode, but in checkbox control check uncheck does not work, please check code done as below:

```
el( components.CheckboxControl, {
    label: i18n.__( 'Display it?', 'txt-domain' ),
    checked: props.attributes.myAttr,
    onChange: function( val ) {
        if( val ) {
            props.setAttributes({ myAttr: '1' })
        } else {
            props.setAttributes({ myAttr: '0' })
        }
    }
} ),
```

if I remove the `checked: props.attributes.myAttr,` then it works fine but here, checkbox does not stay checked or uncheck. by the way it saves the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property checked expects boolean value.  ([CheckboxControl](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/components/checkbox-control/#checked))
How did you define myAttr in attributes?
If you set myAttr to '1' or '0' it is both true.  
Try empty instead of '0' `props.setAttributes({ myAttr: '' })` or false.

Comment: Yes, I have to define string there, just change bool, but here I also need to change in onChange function, like: `onChange: function( val ) { props.setAttributes({ myAttr: val }) }`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the withState wrapper like in the example from the docs : https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/components/checkbox-control/